# deleting only a selected text in a text area

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I want to delete selected text in a text area using Java Swing, but I couldn't find a way to do that. At some point I thought of using `textArea.setText("");` but, when I do, it clears out everything. Can some one please help me with this?

Here is the code I've written so far,

```
public class DeleteTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JPanel panel;
JTextArea textArea;
JButton button;

public DeleteTest() {

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(getBackground().BLACK);
    textArea = new JTextArea(300, 300);
    button = new JButton("clear");

    button.addActionListener(this);

    panel.add(button);

    add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getSource()==button){
        String selected=textArea.getSelectedText();
        if(!selected.equals("")){


        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            DeleteTest de = new DeleteTest();

        }
    };

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna remove only selected text then try this:

```
textArea.setText(textArea.getText().replace(textArea.getSelectedText(),""));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this would fail if a version of the selected text appears more than once in the textarea.

Comment: @George: Yes. But it can be handled by some more efforts. And as per I think OP do not have this kinda case.

Comment: -1, yes this may work, but the solution shows no understanding of how Swing works and therefore is not a very good solution. Using the setText(...) method is expensive and the entire text needs to be parse and the Document needs to be recreated. This is a "String" solution, not a "Text Component" solution.

Answer (score 45):

```
txtArea.replaceSelection("");
```

this should be shorter and more effective.

Comment: +1, much better solution that was designed for a Swing text component.

Comment: Way sweet and way smart!

Answer (score 1):

For **JavaFx TextArea** you can use **deleteText(IndexRange range)** method to delete the selected text.

```java
  textArea.deleteText(textArea.getSelection());
```

To delete text based on index use **deleteText(int start, int end)** overloaded method

```java
  textArea.deleteText(startIndex, endIndex);
```

We can use **replaceSelection(String replacement)** method to delete the text, in fact **deleteText** internally uses **replaceText** method but **deleteText** method will improve the readability of the code.