# Insert text in JTextArea at caret position

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, caret

I would like to insert text into `JTextArea` at the current caret position how to do it? I have found only java script tutorials.

Answer (score 14):

Using **textarea.setText()**; will replace the whole content of your text. Instead of that, you have to use **insert()** method of your text object.

```
textarea.insert("My String Here", textarea.getCaretPosition());
```

You can get the caret position by textObject **.getCaretPosition()** and start adding your text from there.

I also found this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255666/2655623

to sum up:

```
textarea.replaceSelection("");
textarea.insert("My String Here", textarea.getCaretPosition());
```

Comment: this answer appears in the "Low quality posts" queue. You may want to improve it by adding some explanation on your code and why it is better than previous answers.

Comment: My answer with 3 upvotes has been deleted from this topiclong time ago. It was: "I should use:

jta.insert(txt, jta.getCaretPosition());"

Comment: @Yoda uhms, true. Maybe you can try editing it with a broader explanation and then flagging to be undeleted.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the method [`getCaretPosition()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29).

> Returns the position of the text insertion caret for the text
>   component.

Answer (score 4):

Use `getDocument().insertString` instead of `setText` method.

```
textarea.getDocument().insertString(textarea.getCaretPosition(), t, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. First set the Caret position and the insert your text.

```
textarea.setCaretPosition(int posintion)
textarea.setText(yourData);
```

Comment: This won't insert text at the current caret position but at the caret position you want.

Comment: True you can get the current caret position using the method you specified getCaretPosition() or I generally add mouse event listener to text area and set the caret position *onClick*.

Comment: This will replace the content of the textArea. Please check my answer.